# Can't make SHA1 work correctly in Android java

Tags: java, android, hash

I'm trying to hash some bytes, but the hash produced by my code is different than the hash I get using the Linux console.

```
package com.example.javatest;

import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class StartingPoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println(getSHA1("ABC"));
    }


    public static String getSHA1(String s) throws Exception{ // Generate SHA1 hash
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        md.update(s.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0, s.length());
        byte[] sha1Hash = md.digest();
        return convertToHex(sha1Hash);
    }


    public static String convertToHex(byte[] data) { // Convert to a HEX string
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : data) {
            int halfbyte = (b >>> 4) & 0x0F;
            int two_halfs = 0;
            do {
                buf.append((0 <= halfbyte) && (halfbyte <= 9) ? (char) ('0' + halfbyte) : (char) ('a' + (halfbyte - 10)));
                halfbyte = b & 0x0F;
            } while (two_halfs++ < 1);
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }

}
```

The code produces the following hash: 3c01bdbb26f358bab27f267924aa2c9a03fcfdb8

But when executing the following on the Linux console:

```
$ echo "ABC" | sha1sum
```

the result is: c95ad0ce54f903e1568facb2b120ca9210f6778f

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *echo* command also outputs a newline which is then piped into sha1sum, so you need to pipe your sha1sum command without it.

me@vps:~$ `echo -n ABC|sha1sum`
`3c01bdbb26f358bab27f267924aa2c9a03fcfdb8`

```
-n    do not output the trailing newline
```

Comment: Thank you!

`$ echo ABC | hexdump
0000000 4241 0a43
0000004`

`$ echo -n "ABC" | hexdump
0000000 4241 0043
0000003`